# Yii2 Trailing slash always appear on home URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

Trailing slash always appear on home URL ( **www.test.com/** ). 
Even after typing the normal url like **www.test.com**, it is redirected to **www.test.com/**

Here is my url config:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [

                   ...

                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

                ],
    ],
```

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I would like the home page to be loaded like this ( **www.test.com** ) and to be redirected to **www.test.com** even when the user type **www.test.com/** in the url

Comment: Are you sure it's not your browser's behavior? Check in different browser.

Comment: @Bizley That is true. It's a browser's behavior. It is doing it on Chrome, but not on Firefox, Opera. Is this possible to solve it on Chrome?

Comment: This is just a matter of displaying URLs, purely cosmetic. All browsers are ending URLs with slash, just not all of them are displaying it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your explanations.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a trailing slash using .htaccess you can just use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this, but should work without issue.

EDIT:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule .* $0 [R]
```

Comment: Strange, I know the above works... well, I've added an edit for you to try out.